# check if object is castable in Android

Tags: android, xstream

I am using xstream to parse xml to objects.
the result from

```
xstream.fromXML(xmlFile);
```

is an object.

Since i have mutiple xml-schemas, this object could be cast to multipe definition classes.
Is there a way to check if this object is castable to one these classes so I know which format the xml follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `instanceof` like in normal Java.

```
Object obj = xstream.fromXML(xmlFile);
if (obj instanceof MyClass)
  MyClass myObj = (MyClass)obj;
```